# How hide info from my custom text box? (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

In my Windows Phone Application I have a login Page. When I put some text into Pass `TextBox`, the data should be hide with this symbols: "*". How can I hide info from my custom  text box?

```
<ValidationControl:ValidationControl x:Name="txtPIN"  GotFocus="PinTextBox_GotFocus" Margin="0,0,45,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" ValidationContent="Please insert a valid id" LostFocus="PinBoxLostFocus" InputScope="Number" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="200"  MinWidth="220" MinHeight="80"  MaxLength="4" Foreground="Black" Background="#DEFFFFFF" ValidationRule="{StaticResource pinValidationRule}" TextChanged="txtPIN_TextChanged">
    <ValidationControl:ValidationControl.ValidationSymbol>
        <Image Source="img.png" Height="40" Width="40" />
    </ValidationControl:ValidationControl.ValidationSymbol>
</ValidationControl:ValidationControl>
```

**UPDATE**

```
 <ValidationControl:ValidationControl x:Name="txtPIN"  GotFocus="PinTextBox_GotFocus" Margin="0,0,45,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" ValidationContent="Please insert a valid id" LostFocus="PinBoxLostFocus" InputScope="Password" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="200"  MinWidth="220" MinHeight="80"  MaxLength="4" Foreground="Black" Background="#DEFFFFFF" ValidationRule="{StaticResource pinValidationRule}" TextChanged="txtPIN_TextChanged">
```

It doesn't work

Comment: Are you asking to use password characters to obscure the input someone is typing?  There is a `PasswordBox` for that.

Comment: yes, I am asking about how to use password characters to obscure the input, but I don't know how to make it with my custom textbox

Comment: Why are you using a custom control, rather than the framework provided one?

Answer (score 0):

U can use `System.Security.SecureString` to keep it encrypted..

Comment: btw, System.Security.SecureString is not supported on the Windows Phone platform and the question explicitly asks the question for Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

**System.Security.SecureString** is not available on the Windows Phone platform!

Just have a look at the [SecureString Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx).